# how to create custom rest api in android using parse.com

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform, backend

I am using parse.com for using backend in android, so can i create my own custom Api so that i can reduce the Api calls using parse.com.

I am creating one sample application where the users has to register and i need to check whether the registered user is online or not. so now i m retrieving the updatedAt field from server and checking the updated time with my current time and checking whether the particular user is online or not in device side so performance is slow.

Instead of that can i manage the same in parse.com server side?
thank you.

Comment: Refer this link https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide 
You have all the information there.

Comment: I refered that link and tried to get the url for my sample application but it is asking for Username and password. and i entered my parse.com username and password but it failed to login. Can u please help me which username and password it is expecting from me.

Comment: A user knowing if they are online, or knowing if a different user is online? Not sure what and why you're trying to do.

Comment: User want to know whether the different users or online or not.

Comment: I am using one listView and providing the information of the other users in that i need to display that particular user is online or offline so i need this.